# Adding image to question item in the new google form rest api

Tags: google-forms-api

### Is it possible to use image in the google drive? If yes, how? I have tried using https://drive.google.com/uc?id= + id,  but failed.

error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Failed to fetch image from source_uri: [https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%22),
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}

---

Image
{
"contentUri": string,
"altText": string,
"properties": {
object (MediaProperties)
},
"sourceUri": string
}

Answer (score 0):

I use this form

```
update = {
            "requests": [{
            {
                "createItem": {
                    "item": {
                        "imageItem": {
                            "image": {
                                "sourceUri": https://drive.google.com/uc...
                                }
                            }   
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "index": 0
                    }
                },
            },
            ]
        }

service_form.forms().batchUpdate(
      formId=form_id, body=update).execute()
```

Doc https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/batchUpdate